# How to match a cell to a column & return a value based on that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

```
+-------+---+--------------+----+
| A     | B | C            | D  |
+-------+---+--------------+----+
| Mark  |   | Hasan Shahed | 50 |
+-------+---+--------------+----+
| Hasan |   | Saif Alam    | 60 |
+-------+---+--------------+----+
| Kabir |   | Mark Islam   | 70 |
+-------+---+--------------+----+
| Alam  |   | Ena Sanu     | 80 |
+-------+---+--------------+----+
| Sanu  |   | Joes Kabir   | 100|
+-------+---+--------------+----+
```

I want to match A1 to column C. If matched, setvalue B1= corresponding values from column D

Expected Result will be like-

```
+-------+-----+
| A     | B   |
+-------+-----+
| Mark  | 70  |
+-------+-----+
| Hasan | 50  |
+-------+-----+
| Kabir | 100 |
+-------+-----+
| Alam  | 60  |
+-------+-----+
| Sanu  | 80  |
+-------+-----+
```

How can I do that on Excel?

Comment: Can you have two different `Mark`s in column C?

Comment: All values of Col C are unique & don't have duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `VLOOKUP` to do that, with a wildcard:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*",C$1:D$5,2,0)
```

`*` will match anything.